# Xamarin, Android: Timer to animate Text stops after 1 second

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

in my app, I have a simple TextView that is supposed to count numbers down animated. Since the animator class doenst have anything that would do that, I created my own animation using a timer. Basically, whenever the timer is elapsed (every .01 second), the integer that is displayed on my textviews subtracts 10 of itself and then displays it on the textview again. This looks like this:

```
    private void CountHOFNumbers()
    {

        int intHofNumber = 999999;

        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        timer.Interval = 10;
        timer.Elapsed += delegate
        {
            intHofNumber -= 10;
            txtHof.Text = "# " + formatAp(intHofNumber);
        };
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();

    }
```

It does work, but after just a secnd the timer stops. The app doenst crash, it just doesnt count down anymore. Also, it is never the exact same number that it stops on - sometimes it is at 999,913 - then it is as 999,324 and so on. But it never runs for longer than about 1.5 seconds. This is really bothering me. Also, my phone is vibrating from another thread. The timer seems to stops always when the vibration is on. Is there a chance that they correlate? Or am I just doing it all wrong? I'd love some help! Thanks!

Comment: this might be cause u called this method from the constructor which does not ensure it to be processed on the main/ui thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here is the solution:

```
RunOnUiThread(() => txtHof.Text = "# " + formatAp(intHofStartNumber));
```

I'ts weired though, that it started and then stopps. It shouldn't have started to begin with, but anyway - this fixes my issue :)